# Getting Exception while accessing value of JToken - Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue

Tags: c#, json, linq

I am working on a test case to emulate my C# method. I am unable to access the DocumentID property of the JToken using **token["DocumentID"]**. I am getting System.InvalidOperationException - "Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue".

```
string response = "[\r\n  \"{ \\\"DocumentID\\\": \\\"fakeGuid1\\\",\\\"documentNotes\\\": \\\"TestNotes1\\\"}\"\r\n]";
//Response has escape charaters as  this is being returned by a mockMethod which is supposed to return JSon.ToString().

string[] fakeGuidForExecutiveSummary = new string[]{"fakeGuid1"};
string fakeResponseFromExecutiveSummaryProxy = "{ \"DocumentID\": \"fakeGuid1\",\"documentNotes\": \"TestNotes1\"}";

JArray jsonResponse = JArray.Parse(response);
//Value of jsonResponse from Debugger - {[  "{ \"DocumentID\": "fakeGuid1\",\"documentNotes\": \"TestNotes1\"}" ]}

JToken token = jsonResponse[0];
//Value of token from Debugger - { "DocumentID": fakeGuid1","documentNotes": "TestNotes1"}
Assert.AreEqual(fakeGuidForExecutiveSummary[0], token["DocumentID"]);
```

Comment: What is `response`?  Also, you are not using `fakeResponseFromExecutiveSummaryProxy` at all, so what JSON are you actually using?

Comment: Also, what is `fakeGuidForExecutiveSummary`?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code that demonstrates your problem.  Since you omit some steps (like initializing `fakeGuidForExecutiveSummary`) we can only guess what the problem is.

Comment: fakeGuidForExecutiveSummary equals the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how you initialize `fakeGuidForExecutiveSummary`.  Assuming you do it in the following way:

```
        string fakeResponseFromExecutiveSummaryProxy = "{ \"DocumentID\": \"fakeGuid1\",\"documentNotes\": \"TestNotes1\"}";
        var fakeResponse = JToken.Parse(fakeResponseFromExecutiveSummaryProxy);
        var fakeGuidForExecutiveSummary = fakeResponse["DocumentID"];
```

Then the problem is that `fakeGuidForExecutiveSummary` is a [`JValue`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm), not a [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) or [`JArray`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm).  Your code will throw the exception you see if you try to access a (nonexistent) child value by index.

Instead you need to do the following:

```
        string response = @"[{ ""DocumentID"": ""fakeGuid1"",""documentNotes"": ""TestNotes1""}]";
        JArray jsonResponse = JArray.Parse(response);
        JToken token = jsonResponse[0];

        //Value of token from Debugger - { "DocumentID": fakeGuid1","documentNotes": "TestNotes1"}
        Assert.AreEqual(fakeGuidForExecutiveSummary, token["DocumentID"])
```

**Update**

Given your updated code, the problem is that your sample JSON `response` has too many levels of string escaping: `\\\"DocumentID\\\"`.  You probably copied escaped strings shown in Visual Studio into the source code, then escaped them some again.

Change it to

```
        string response = "[\r\n  { \"DocumentID\": \"fakeGuid1\",\"documentNotes\": \"TestNotes1\"}\r\n]";
```

Comment: I edited my question to be more accurate. This is very close to my problem, I tried your solution but still get same error.

Comment: Adding an additinal line  to your above code worked
JToken token = JToken.Parse(jsonResponse[0].ToString());